# Empty line before input prompt on Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

When I run the code

```
print("Hi")
input("Hello: ")
```

on [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) (Python 3.6), I get the expected output (ignoring my input)

```
Hi
Hello:
```

However, when I run the same two lines on my computer, using Spyder 3.3.1 and Python 3.7 I get the output

```
Hi

Hello:
```

I would like to understand why this blank line appears in Spyder, and also how to get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried running the code using the command line calling the Python script instead of using Spyder and seeing if the same thing happened? I cannot reproduce what you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Spyder's bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16504) and it was fixed in its **5.3.1** version, released on May 2022.

*Note*: Please be sure to also have version 5.3.1 of the Qtconsole package to avoid a bug that appeared while fixing this one.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's question has two parts:

1. "I would like to understand why this blank line appears in Spyder,…"
2. "…and also how to get rid of it."

Martijn Pieters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53133907/10191355), where he points out that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5242), only addresses the first part. This answer addresses the second.

Do the following to remove `print`'s default newline:

```
print("Hi", end="")
input("Hello: ")
```

Which will return:

```
Hi
Hello:
```

**Take note**: This is a bit of a hack, i.e. it does not remove the newline that precedes `input`. As a result, if you run your script anywhere other than in Spyder the above code will return:

```
HiHello:
```

Since this is a minor quirk that is specific to Spyder, it likely makes more sense just to tolerate it and move on.

Comment: I do not think that the expected output wanted them on the same line, it wanted them to not have a blank line in between the `print` and `input()`

Comment: They are not asking how to remove a newline. They are asking why Spyder adds **an extra** newline when you use `input()` after `print()`.

Comment: But because of the bug in Spyder this actually removes the blank line between the two outputs