# How to remove the space between two input statements in python?

Tags: python, input, spyder

```
name = input ("Please enter the participant's name: ")
age = int (input ("Please enter the valid age of the participant: "))
```

Output:

```
Please enter the participant's name: abc

Please enter the valid age of the participant: 21
```

***How can I get rid of the space between the two lines?***

Comment: Not reproducible.

Comment: How are you running this? There's no space when I run it in a normal terminal.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, we can't?

Comment: @interjay Spyder

Comment: @JeevaniReddy, check out [Empty line before input prompt on Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53133795/10824407).

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This bug is fixed in our current version (5.3.1), released last May. But you also need to be sure to have Qtconsole 5.3.1 to avoid a bug that appeared due to that.